# How remove Ubuntu software itself?

Tags: software-uninstall

How remove Ubuntu software itself?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are referring to the Ubuntu Software application. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options;

If you would prefer to just make it disappear, run `snap disable snap-store` in a terminal.

If you really want it to be taken behind the woodshed, instead run `snap remove snap-store` in a terminal.

The first option will still leave it on your system, but it won't be active or receive any updates.

The second option will completely remove it from your system.